# Wordpress Theme Duplicate but displaying differently on different domains

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I decided to mirror a wordpress design I created onto another domain

http://www.global-markets-recruitment.com/

However once I copied the code over to the new domain the logo appears out of position when the screen is moved rather than moving with the website frame

http://www.keylexconsulting.com/wp/#home

The CSS and HTML is exactly the same but I can't see why they vary

```
/*
Theme Name:     Child
Description:    This is a child theme
Author:         Laura Dawaf
*/

body
{
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 180%;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #EEEFF1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5b5b5b;
}

a:focus
{
    outline: none;
}

a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


#header {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#logo {
    font-size: 28px;
}

#logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 105px;
    background: url(Assets/logo.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

#logo h1
{
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -2000px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 850px;
}

#nav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav li
{
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 34px 10px 34px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url(Assets/Nav/navSplitLine.gif) no-repeat right top;
}

#nav li.end
{
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 34px 10px 34px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: none;
}

#nav li a#navHome
{
    display: block;
    width: 46px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(Assets/Nav/home.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#nav li a#navHome:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

#nav li a#navArtScience
{
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(Assets/Nav/artScience.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li a#navArtScience:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

#nav li a#navContext
{
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(Assets/Nav/context.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li a#navContext:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}

#nav li a#navContact
{
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(Assets/Nav/contact.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li a#navContact:hover
{
    background-position: 0px -20px;
}


#footerContainer
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95px;
    margin: 550px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(Assets/footerBg.png) repeat-x 0px 0px;
}

#footer
{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 11px;
}

#footerNav {
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    top: -576px;
}

#footerNav ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#footerNav li
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 6px 0px 11px;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url(Assets/footerSplitLine.png) no-repeat 0px 5px;
}

#footerNav li.start
{
    padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
    background: none;
}

#footerNav li a
{
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#footerNav li a:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#footerStrap
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
}

#footerStrap img
{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#footerDetails
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 48px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

/* Nav Slider */

#navPointer
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 7px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#controlContainer
{
    width: 713px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#pointer
{
    width: 713px;
    height: 7px;
    background: url(Assets/pointer.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}


/* Content Slider */

#contentHolder
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 110;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -600px;
}

#contentShadow
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: -10;
    background: url(Assets/bgShadow-trans.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

#contentGallery
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 550px;
    z-index: -100;
}

#content {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 550px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 500;
}

#contentScroller
{
     width: 100000px;
}

.page
{
    float: left;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0px 1200px 0px 0px;
    height: 550px;
}

.pageContent
{
    width: 640px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0px 100px 0px 460px;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(http://www.keylexconsulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/pageBg-trans.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.closed
{
    display: none;
}

.headerText
{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 35px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: url(Assets/dottedLine.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
    color: #4484A9;
}

.pageText
{
    width: 560px;
    min-height: 385px;
    padding: 25px 35px 0px 35px;
    color: #5B5B5B;
}

h2
{
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h3
{
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h3 a
{
    color: #FBB034;
}

h3 a:hover
{
    color: #5B5B5B;
}

.homeContent
{
    width: 424px;
    height: 470px;
    margin: 0px 100px 0px 680px;
    padding: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: url(http://www.keylexconsulting.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/pageBg-trans.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.homeHeaderText
{
    float: left;
    width: 389px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-size: 43px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 22px;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(Assets/dottedLine.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
    color: #4484A9;
    text-align: center;
}

.homeStrap
{
    width: 354px;
    padding: 15px 35px 0px 35px;
}

.homePageText
{
    width: 380px;
    padding: 40px 35px 0px 22px;
    color: #5B5B5B;
}

/* accordian */


a.acc_trigger, a.acc_trigger_2, a.acc_trigger_3
{
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(Assets/arrow.gif) no-repeat right 5px;
    line-height: 240%;
    color: #4484A9;
}

a.acc_trigger:hover, a.acc_trigger_2:hover, a.acc_trigger_3:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

a.active
{
    background: none;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #5B5B5B;
}

.acc_container, .acc_container_2, .acc_container_3
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 560px;
    clear: both;
}

.acc_container p, .acc_container_2 p, .acc_container_3 p
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a.acc_trigger:hover, a.acc_trigger_2:hover, a.acc_trigger_3:hover {
    color: #4484A9;
}

.seperator
{
    height: 3px;
}

/* classes */

.clear
{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: none;
}

a.largeArrow
{
    padding: 0px 18px 0px 35px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: url(Assets/largeArrow.gif) no-repeat right 4px;
    line-height: 100%;
    color: #FBB034;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.largeArrow:hover
{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* links & tables */

.linkTable
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.linkTable td
{
    width: 45%;
}

.hentry, .no-results {
    display: none;
}

#primary {
    display: none;
}

#page {
    background: #EEEFF1;
    margin: 0px;
}

#site-generator {
    background: #EEEFF1;
    padding: 0px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #666666;
}

#footerNav li a:hover {
    color: #4484A9;
}

small a {   
    color: #4484A9 !important;
}

#sidebar {  
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hit and run? If you end up using an answer, please mark it as accepted or clarify what you still need resolved.

Comment: I have marked the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome developer tools on the first link I see:

```
<body class="home blog single-author two-column right-sidebar">
```

On the second I see:

```
<body class="home page page-id-275 page-template page-template-page-fullwidth-php">
```

If the templates were applied identically, wouldn't both be the same?

Comment: How odd. I copied everything directly over. Is it possible for me to edit the body class?

Comment: It kinda depends on how your template is setup, but wherever your template (either in index.php or some other partial .php) sets up the body tag, that's probably where it also sets its class attributes.

Comment: Is one version setting a static front page, and the other not? Double check your Reading Settings (Settings->Reading) on both sites.

Comment: The static front page was causing the problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: @user1096057 Cool. Please mark Killnine's answer as accepted, as he was the one who noticed the discrepancy in the class names.